# How to use react router to achieve step by step navigation (like in a slideshow)?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

## I currently have this working:

[image]

## But what I want to achieve is this:

[image]

## And this is my code:

```
            <Link to={'/assessment/01'} className="dropdown-item">Assessment 1</Link>
            <Link to={'/assessment/02'} className="dropdown-item">Assessment 2</Link>
            <Link to={'/assessment/03'} className="dropdown-item">Assessment 3</Link>
          </nav> <br/>

          <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/create' component={ Create } />
              <Route path='/edit/:id' component={ Edit } />
              <Route path='/index' component={ Index } />
              <Route path='/assessment/01' component={ Assessment_01 } />
              <Route path='/assessment/02' component={ Assessment_02 } />
              <Route path='/assessment/03' component={ Assessment_03 } />
          </Switch>
```

How do I route like the second example?

Comment: This should just be a case of markup change, instead of having links as drop down items, have them as buttons on each individual component.

Comment: I hope, my answer will help you. @Harish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to conditionally render the links based on your current route.

For example.

```
 render(){
 <div>
  <h1>Welcome to assessment</h1>
   {props.location.pathname === '/assessment/01' && <Link to='/assessment/02' className="dropdown-item">Assessment 2</Link>}
   {props.location.pathname === '/assessment/02' && <Link to='/assessment/03' className="dropdown-item">Assessment 3</Link>}
   {props.location.pathname === '/assessment/03' && <Link to='/assessment/01' className="dropdown-item">Assessment 3</Link>}
 </div>
 }
```

Like this. Hope this will help you.

Edit: check out the fiddle [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-fire-278kk) and [demo](https://8fkrp.csb.app/assessment/01)

Comment: It says `this` is undefined

Comment: I think you are using functional component, Then you can use `props`  without `this` keyword.

Comment: it says `props` is undefined as well

Comment: Okay, let me send u a fiddle for example.

Comment: check this https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-8fkrp @Harish

Comment: there is a typo in the answer `location` is spelled as `loaction`

Comment: Yes, I noticed it while writing the fiddle. Thanks! @Harish